# Leak into bowl and no water flow to overflow tube

Tags: toilet

The toilet had a leak from under the front of the bowl rim and all the parts were replaced. The leak is still there. Now, after the flush valve was removed and reset, no water comes out of the hose from the fill valve into the overflow tube. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It sounds like you now have a new problem; perhaps a picture of the flush valve would help. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: "a leak from under the front of the bowl rim"; do you mean that water was running (post flush) and coming into the bowl from the holes at the front of the bowl rim? The mechanism that lifts and allows water to flow from the tank/cistern into the bowl is usually called the "flush valve", is this what was replaced or was it the *fill valve* (aka ballcock valve)? The flush valve is (generally) unrelated to the fill valve, so the symptoms described do not correlate; please post pictures.